# Splitting strings and converting df from long to wide format with one-hot encoding

Tags: python, pandas

Below is script for a simplified version of the df in question:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 
               'id' : [1,1,2,2,3,3], 
               'feature': ['colour','interior_features','colour','interior_features','colour','interior_features'],
               'feature_value' : ['blue','cd_player<->sat_nav<->usb_port','red','cd_player<->usb_port','red','cd_player<->sat_nav<->sub_woofer'],
                 })
df

   id   feature             feature_value
0   1   colour              blue
1   1   interior_features   cd_player<->sat_nav<->usb_port
2   2   colour              red
3   2   interior_features   cd_player<->usb_port
4   3   colour              red
5   3   interior_features   cd_player<->sat_nav<->sub_woofer
```

First of all, I would like to convert the string in *'interior_features'*   into a list, where `'<->'` is the separator, as per below:

```
    id  feature             feature_value
0   1   colour              blue
1   1   interior_features   [cd_player, sat_nav, usb_port]
2   2   colour              red
3   2   interior_features   [cd_player, usb_port]
4   3   colour              red
5   3   interior_features   [cd_player, sat_nav, sub_woofer]
```

Then I would like to unnest this list and use one-hot encoding to assign binary value to *'interior_features'* in the *'feature_value'* column.

INTENDED DF:

```
    id  feature     feature_value
0   1   colour      blue
1   1   cd_player   1
2   1   sat_nav     1
3   1   usb_port    1
4   1   sub_woofer  0
5   2   colour      red
6   2   cd_player   1
7   2   sat_nav     0
8   2   usb_port    1
9   2   sub_woofer  0
10  3   colour      red
11  3   cd_player   1
12  3   sat_nav     1
13  3   usb_port    0
14  3   sub_woofer  1
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `split` then `explode` and `crosstab` fill the miss row for each id

```
df1 = df.loc[df['feature']=='colour'] 
# slice out the row do not need to unnest
df2 = df.drop(df1.index)    
df2['feature'] = df2['feature_value'].str.split('<->')
s = df2.explode('feature') 
s = pd.crosstab(s['id'],s['feature']).stack().reset_index(name='feature_value')
out = pd.concat([df1,s]).sort_values('id')
out
Out[356]: 
    id     feature feature_value
0    1      colour          blue
0    1   cd_player             1
1    1     sat_nav             1
2    1  sub_woofer             0
3    1    usb_port             1
2    2      colour           red
4    2   cd_player             1
5    2     sat_nav             0
6    2  sub_woofer             0
7    2    usb_port             1
4    3      colour           red
8    3   cd_player             1
9    3     sat_nav             1
10   3  sub_woofer             1
11   3    usb_port             0
```